# How to post php variables in swf?

Tags: php, flash, actionscript

I have in test.php this:

```
$domain = $_GET['domain'];
$user = $_GET['user'];
```

and in my Action Script i have:

```
getURL("http://test.com/file.php?domain=?&user=?", "_blank");
```

How do get variables from php and put in my swf?

I'm beginner in flash!!!

Answer (score 0):

To send variables from flash to PHP:

```
//Actionscript:
loadVariables ("test.php?myVariable=" + myFlashVar , _root);

//PHP can retrieve it using
$myVar = $_GET['myVariable'];
```

To send from PHP to flash, use exactly the same:

```
//Actionscript:
loadVariables ("test.php?" , _root);

//PHP:
echo "&myVariable=hello";

//Now in your flash movie, _root.myVariable will be equal to 'hello'
```

I hope this is enough to get you started :)

Comment: and how should be: `getURL("http://test.com/file.php?domain=?&user=?", "_blank");` ?

Comment: getURL wont allow you to send the variables in the background. getURL will open a new window with the page in it. IF this is what you actually want, then you should change the ? as here :-:---  getURL("http://test.com/file.php?domain=" + myDomain + "&user=" + myUser, "_blank");       'myDomain' and 'myUser' would be variables from the flash actionscript.

Comment: ok. How is action script with two variables and i should put anyting in my player code ?

Comment: Just place a textbox on stage using the drawing tools, and make sure that the textbox has the name 'input1'. Then add to your code myDomain=input1.text; and you will obtain the information. this should be enough to get you started. Follow this link for tutorials to learn actionscript more indepth: http://www.actionscript.org/resources/categories/Tutorials/

Comment: i don't know how is made! Is first time when i make swf! Can you make all for me for that exemple ? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not going to do the work for you. The idea of Stack Overflow is that the person asking the question shows that they are trying to do the goal them self with a little help from the community. You are asking for someone to develop this program for you from scratch. Go here: http://goo.gl/MZp3nq